# How long has EStackOverflow been deprecated and what replaces it?

Tags: delphi, exception, deprecated, stack-overflow

I noticed that EStackOverflow, as defined in SysUtils.pas is marked as deprecated in Delphi 2009.  I checked and it was also marked as deprecated in 2007.  I have a Delphi 7 install disk here, but I thought I would ask if anyone knows when it was deprecated.

Additionally, does anyone know why, and what replaces it?  I wrote a test application that causes a Stack Overflow through recursion, and I still get an EStackOverflow exception, but if I add a handler specifically for it then I get

> [DCC Warning] Unit57.pas(85): W1000 Symbol 'EStackOverflow' is deprecated

I know that EStackOverflow descends from EExternal, and that I could trap EExternal and check ExceptionCode  for STATUS_STACK_OVERFLOW, but that seems unnecessary since it still throws the EStackOverflow exception.

Is this just to discourage me from throwing an EStackOverflow in my own code?

*(Yes, I realize the irony of asking a question about **EStackOverflow** on a website called **StackOverflow**, and yes **I am completely serious**.)*

Comment: I tried to google for stack overflow problems, and I got loads of links into stackoverflow.com... :-) but I did manage to find this one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't have D5 here to say, but I barely remember the **deprecated** directive 
appeared only on D6.

As for StackOverflow exception, I think it's deprecated because is only for Delphi runtime environment to raise it.

EDIT: Based on the aggregate of all the answers, EStackOverflow was deprecated in Delphi 6 when the Deprecated keyword was introduced.

Answer (score 4):

Just like in .NET, you cant really catch a StackOverflow exception, what do you recover to? Your code is most likely wrong if you need to catch one :)

Comment: I actually want to have a line that says "on EStackOverflow do raise;" so I don't catch it.  But you may be right.  Instead I decided to trap EExternal and check ExceptionCode for STATUS_STACK_OVERFLOW

Answer (score 2):

I just checked my Delphi 6, and EStackOverflow is already deprecated.  I don't have access to older versions of Delphi here.

I can't help you with the why or the possible replacement.

Answer (score 2):

In Delphi 5 it's not yet deprecated.

edit: Actually, in Delphi 5, 'deprecated' is not a reserved word.

Answer (score 1):

> Is this just to discourage me from throwing an EStackOverflow in my own code?

More importantly, I think this means you should not design code to depend on it being thrown in future versions.